# Is there a more efficient way to insert an array of data inside my database? Asp.net-core + Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dapper

Is there any way to make this more efficient? It takes too long when I insert an array of 50+ items.

The method gets called by my API controller.

Thanks in advance, I'm still new to this stuff.

```
DataAccess data = new DataAccess();

[HttpPost]
public void Post(Contract[] contractList)
{
    data.insertContracts(contractList);
}

public class DataAccess
{
    public  void insertList(Contract[] contractList)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
        {
            foreach (var item in contractList)
            {
                 Execute("dbo.spInsertContract @contract_Id, @color, @contract_Type, @ne_Type, @storn, @dispo_Id, @kw, @create_Date, @termin_Date", item);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: How long is "too long" ?

Comment: Instead of inserting one item at a time, why don't you use the user defined table data type and pass all contacts those need to be inserted/updated at storage with datatype as input and let stored procedure uses either Join or Merge to insert all records at once.... If the number of records are huge like >5k then you can think of Bulk update option also (there are libraries which can be used)l

Comment: What is `dbo.spInsertContract` doing? Please [edit] your question to include the content of that stored procedure. Also, why do you not use a prepared statement to use for all the items in the `contractList` array?

Comment: Depends how many records you have... for bulk inserts i still use SqlBulkCopy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: You’re not inserting records, you are running a stored procedure likely many times. There’s no way to “make this more efficient” without _not running_ the stored procedure.

Comment: the points to reduce the inserting time here are: (1) reduce the number of transactions (including auto/implicit transaction) (2) reduce the number of connections (executions). So you need to prepare your command text to include all the items and execute that in one transaction. As in your code, there are multiple implicit transactions for each `Execute`, also each such `Execute` makes one round-trip to the db. Almost ORMs help you insert data conveniently but not the most efficiently. You usually need to code it on your own (or using some nuget package)

Comment: Have you looked at the main Dapper site https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper and read the section entitled *Execute a Command multiple times*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works fine and its performance is comparable to the regular approach. So it is not really a way to insert big amounts of data. An ideal way to go here is to use [SQL Bulk Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and forget about Dapper.

```
public async Task InsertList(Contract[] contractList)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
    {
        var parameters = contractList.Select(u =>
        {
            var tempParams = new DynamicParameters();
            tempParams.Add("@contract_Id", u, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
            tempParams.Add("@color", u, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            tempParams.Add(" @contract_Type", u, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            ...
            return tempParams;
        });

        await connection.ExecuteAsync("INSERT INTO [Contract] (contract_Id, color, contract_Type, ...) VALUES ( @contract_Id, @color, @contract_Type,...)", 
            parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dennyy are you sure that the exact code above works? the parameters are built wrong, the parameter values are all `u`, not something like `u.ContractId` (for `@contract_id`), `u.Color` (for `@color`), ... it looks fairly magical. Looks like it can even automap the name `@contact_id` with the corresponding property from the object `u` of type `Contract`.